# ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

On Mac Catalina OS, while installing Ruby with rbenv, I am getting this error.

```
Last 10 log lines:
The Ruby openssl extension was not compiled.
ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions
Configure options used:
  --prefix=/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8
  --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1
  --enable-shared
  --with-readline-dir=/usr/local/opt/readline
  CC=clang
  LDFLAGS=-L/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib 
  CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/include
```

EDIT - I have attached the solution which I found and worked for me. I hope this helps others too.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with OpenSSL. Mac CommandLine Tools is coming with OpenSSL 1.1 whereas you need OpenSSL 1.0. This is the solution for it

```
$ brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0

$ RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.0)" rbenv install 2.5.8
```

This will install Ruby 2.5.8. Do not forget to set

```
rbenv global 2.5.8
```

to make it work

Comment: This solution is still working for me on macOS 12.1 and Ruby 3.0.3